# Split string after hex values

Tags: python

My string:

```
 str1 = "Text\x11\x05\x11MoreTEXT\x02HELLO\x011"
```

I want to get all strings between \xYY. I would like to get a list like this:

```
list1 = ["Text", "MoreTEXT", "HELLO", "1"]
```

Notice that \xYY can occure more times in a row like in my example at the beginning. How can I split it like I want it?

Comment: `re.sub(r'[^\w]', '', str1)` which removed only `\\`

Comment: `re.split('[\x01-\x1f\x7f]', str1)` which adds `\\`before \x...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this technique. Just substitute the hex values with spaces, then split at a series of spaces.

```
new_string = re.split('\s+', re.sub('[\x01-\x1f\x7f]', ' ', str1))
```

Comment: nice! just realized an even shorter solution: `str_split = re.split('[\x01-\x1f\x7f]+', str1)`

Answer (score 0):

You're close!

```
str_split = re.split('[\x01-\x1f\x7f]', str1)
str_lst = [s for s in str_split if s != '']
```

The first line splits the list, however it returns `''` list elements if there are consecutive delimiters.
The second line removes the blank elements from the list.

Comment: Actually I get the excact same result (addition of `\\\`). The second line is not working for me.

Comment: http://pythonfiddle.com/re-split here's the full code I used. Seems to produce the desired output.