# Regex hexadecimal with exception

Tags: python, regex

The following string

```
str1 = "Hello\x00MORE\x11\x20TEXT\x05here"
```

should be converted to this list (remove all hexadecimal strings except \x20 which should be a whitespace):

```
list1 = ['Hello', 'MORE TEXT', 'here']
```

So far my solution is:

```
new_list = re.split('\s+', re.sub('[\x01-\x1f\x7f]', ' ', s))
```

It produces:

```
list1 = ['Hello', 'MORE', 'TEXT', 'here']
```

but as you can see I need `MORE TEXT` to be one string so `\x20` should be converted to a whitespace. How can I use my regex with the exception to not consider `\x20` ?

Comment: FYI: [Split string after hex values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28612251/split-string-after-hex-values)

Comment: there is no exception for \x20 in this example

Comment: Any reason you're asking this from the different account?

Comment: Not me. However I saw this question and had the same problem but with this little \x20 exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> [re.sub(r'[\x00-\x1f\x7f ]+',' ',i) for i in re.split(r'(?<=[a-z])[\x00-\x1f\x7f]|[\x00-\x1f\x7f](?=[a-z])',str1)]
['Hello', 'MORE TEXT', 'here']
```

First you can split your string based on the following regex :

```
r'(?<=[a-z])[\x00-\x1f\x7f]|[\x00-\x1f\x7f](?=[a-z])'
```

This pattern that using [look-around](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) split your string by hex numbers between `\x00` and `\x1f\x7f` that preceding by a lowercase letter, or (`|`) hex numbers between `\x00` and `\x1f\x7f` that following by a lowercase letter! then you'll have the following result :

```
['Hello', 'MORE\x11 TEXT', 'here']
```

Now you need to replace the hex numbers with an empty string or as i done you can replace any combination of hex numbers with space with 1 space.